# Assure minimal wait between calls with decorators

Tags: python, decorator

I'm building a wrapper for an API which demands at least 1 second of waiting between each call. I thought I could solve this using a decorator in the following way:

```
import datetime, time

last_time = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1)

def interval_assurer(f):
    global last_time
    if (datetime.datetime.now() - last_time).seconds < 1:
        print("Too fast...")
        time.sleep(1)

    last_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    return f

@interval_assurer
def post():
    pass
```

This won't work though, for some reason, and I'm not sure why. `last_time` gets updated the first time the `post` is called, but won't update afterwards. Please keep in mind that this is the first time I'm experimenting with decorators, so I am probably missing something fundamental.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorator function just returns the original function, so the timing code *only runs when the decorator is called*, i.e. when the function definition is evaluated. Instead, it should return *a new function* that incorporates the timing code and calls `f` when appropriate.

Try something like:

```
def interval_assurer(f):
    def func():
        global last_time
        if (datetime.datetime.now() - last_time).seconds < 1:
            print("Too fast...")
            time.sleep(1)
        last_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        return f()
    return func
```

If your decorated function takes arguments, you should include `*args, **kwargs` in the definition of `func` and the call to `f`; also, consider decorating `func` in turn with [`functools.wraps(f)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

---

Building on @bereal's answer, you can make the `last_time` an attribute of the wrapper function to remove the `global` (allowing multiple wrapped functions, each with their own timer), and even make a decorator that takes an argument for the interval to enforce:

```
import functools
import time

def interval_assured(interval):
    """Ensure consecutive calls are separated by a minimal interval."""
    def wrapper(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            if (time.time() - func.last_time) < interval:
                time.sleep(interval)
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            func.last_time = time.time()
            return result
        func.last_time = time.time()
        return func
    return wrapper
```

**Note** that the time is reset *after* the wrapped function `f` is called - this is important if the run-time of `f` is large relative to the interval.

In use:

```
>>> def testing(x):
    print time.time()
    print x


>>> for x in range(3):
    testing(x)


1405938405.97
0
1405938406.01
1
1405938406.02
2
>>> @interval_assured(5)
def testing(x):
    print time.time()
    print x


>>> for x in range(3):
    testing(x)


1405938429.71
0
1405938434.73
1
1405938439.75
2
```

Comment: I have edited to add a more complex implementation with some of the more advanced features of Python's decorators.

Answer (score 4):

Since your `interval_assurer` is a decorator, it's called exactly once: when the function is defined, and not when it's called. You need to create a wrapping function like this:

```
import time, functools

def interval_assurer(f):
    last_time = [0]
    @functools.wraps(f)  # optional, but nice to have
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        time_diff = time.time() - last_time[0]
        if time_diff < 1:
            print("Too fast...")
            time.sleep(1 - time_diff)

         last_time[0] = time.time()   
         return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@interval_assurer
def post(self, **kwargs):
    pass
```

You also won't need the global then (the trick with the list can be replaced with `nonlocal` in Python 3).